# Scroll function does not fire an animation properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I do have a simple `.scroll()` function to fire an event, if the `.scrollTop()` of the body is higher than a specific value:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($('body, html').scrollTop() > 250) {
        console.log("higher");
        $('#navbar').animate({paddingTop: 5, paddingBottom: 5}, 'slow');
    } else {
        console.log("lower");
        $('#navbar').animate({paddingTop: 25, paddingBottom: 25}, 'slow');
    }
});
```

Problem I have is, that it fires the function for every scrolling pixel. I just want to fire the animation depending on the `scrollTop` value.

How can I solve this the best way?

Thanks

Comment: For every pixel of scrolling, you would either get a higher or lower. Your code is working as expected.

Comment: @cforcloud correct, but I just want to detect the `scrollTop` value, not fire the animation on every scrolling pixel.

Comment: you could use a delay to get the value only every x seconds or a scrollTop difference to get it every x pixels

Comment: You could use something like throttle http://underscorejs.org/#throttle

Comment: or do you want to fire just once?

Comment: @Andi what I basically wanna do is, if the `scrollTop` is higher than value x, do animation. If not then do animation back.

Comment: you need a blocking variable then. I write some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var _top, _last_top = -1;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    _top = $('body, html').scrollTop();

    if(_top > 250 && _last_top < 250) {
        _last_top = _top;
        $('#navbar').animate({paddingTop: 5, paddingBottom: 5}, 'slow');
    }

    if(_top < 250 && _last_top > 250) {
        _last_top = _top;
        $('#navbar').animate({paddingTop: 25, paddingBottom: 25}, 'slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: Check out the window version. I can't actually believe this works okay in the latest Chrome :/.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're getting `scrollTop` values from both `body` and `html` in the function. Depending on the browser this will give you some unpredictable results. You should just get the `scrollTop` value of `body`.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log($('body').scrollTop());
    if($('body').scrollTop() > 250) {
        console.log("higher");
        $('#navbar').animate({paddingTop: 5, paddingBottom: 5}, 'slow');
    } else {
        console.log("lower");
        $('#navbar').animate({paddingTop: 25, paddingBottom: 25}, 'slow');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xxs82dsk/

**Edit:** Apparently getting `scrollTop` value of `window` fixes the problem cross-browser. Works in FF and Chrome for me:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 250) {
        console.log("higher");
        $('#navbar').animate({paddingTop: 5, paddingBottom: 5}, 'slow');
    } else {
        console.log("lower");
        $('#navbar').animate({paddingTop: 25, paddingBottom: 25}, 'slow');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ushopako/

Comment: I think this is needed for crossbrowser! Gecko uses a different element than Webkit to read the scrollTop of the `body`.

Comment: Try it. My example does work as expected in the latest Chrome. It does the oposite in Firefox however. You should use `html` in firefox... Not sure why yet. FF version: http://jsfiddle.net/xxs82dsk/2/

Comment: Use window instead of body or html. Works like a charm in both. ;)

Answer (score 0):

With a blocker variable, this should work.

```
var animateOnce = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($('body, html').scrollTop() > 250) {
        if(animateOnce == false) {
            $('#navbar').animate({paddingTop: 5, paddingBottom: 5}, 'slow');
        }
        animateOnce = true;
    } else {
        if(animateOnce == true) {
            $('#navbar').animate({paddingTop: 25, paddingBottom: 25}, 'slow');
        }
        animateOnce = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: the `> 200` works well, but it doesn't animate back when `< 200`